# Blazor WASM : .NET CORE 6 RC1 Invalid /api routes are returning HTML instead of NOT Found

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I am developing Blazor Wasm Hosted App using VS 2022 Preview 4 and .NET core RC1
I am running into problem; If i pass an invalid URL like `"/api/{invalidcontroller}/{valid method}"` or  `"/api/{validController}/{InvlaidMethod}`

Instead of return route Not Found error i am getting back index.html.

I tried

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{**slug:regex((?!api.*)):nonfile}", "index.html");
```

as pointed out somewhere, but that did not work either

How can I exclude falling back to "index.html" when URL has "/api/XXXXX" in the route and instead return error route not found ?

Comment: This is a pain but also a sensible fallback. The server has no idea who the caller is, as all calls come from the browser. Where did you see that `MapFallbackToFile("{**slug:regex((?!api.*)):nonfile}", "index.html");` would work? What did you try? Perhaps your code needs a fix, perhaps RC1 has a different way to do the same